# VB: Assigning Datatable to another DataTable without importing the records.

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Assuming I have two DataTable - DT_A and DT_B

DT_A has 3 columns - id, name and phone
DT_A has few records such as (1,'Sherry','01523652452'),...

Now I am assigning DT_A to DT_B like this

DT_B = DT_A

DT_B will get all the columns format and records as well. I know I can just clear the records after assigning but I want to know is there any other better way to just get the columns format without the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to change that line to:

```
DT_B = DT_A.Clone
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx

---

(some code to demonstrate)

```
    Dim dtA As New DataTable
    Dim dtB As New DataTable

    dtA.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Index"))
    dtA.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name"))
    dtA.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Number"))

    Debug.WriteLine("DATATABLE A COLUMNS")
    Debug.WriteLine(dtA.Columns(0).ColumnName)
    Debug.WriteLine(dtA.Columns(1).ColumnName)
    Debug.WriteLine(dtA.Columns(2).ColumnName)

    dtA.Rows.Add({"1", "Sherry", "01523652452"})
    dtA.Rows.Add({"2", "Bob", "0937948573"})

    Debug.WriteLine("DATATABLE A RECORDS")
    For Each row As DataRow In dtA.Rows
        Debug.WriteLine(row(0) & " " & row(1) & " " & row(2))
    Next

    dtB = dtA.Clone

    Debug.WriteLine("DATATABLE B COLUMNS")
    Debug.WriteLine(dtB.Columns(0).ColumnName)
    Debug.WriteLine(dtB.Columns(1).ColumnName)
    Debug.WriteLine(dtB.Columns(2).ColumnName)

    Debug.WriteLine("DATATABLE B RECORDS")
    For Each row As DataRow In dtB.Rows
        Debug.WriteLine(row(0) & " " & row(1) & " " & row(2))
    Next
```

---

Gives me this output:

DATATABLE A COLUMNS
Index
Name
Number
DATATABLE A RECORDS
1 Sherry 01523652452
2 Bob 0937948573
DATATABLE B COLUMNS
Index
Name
Number
DATATABLE B RECORDS